# magento2 REST APIs order comments

Tags: magento2

I have read probably all the [swagger](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/), but I don't find an answer for this.

I want to place an order with a user-defined comment, so I would like to find an API call that requires a "self" permission and that can associate a comment with a quote, that later will be converted to an order.
The point is that I have only found API calls that require an admin access and directly on the order object, for example: `POST /rest/V1/orders/{id}/comments`.

Is there anything already defined in the core Magento2 APIs or do I have to implement/extend an API by myself?

Thanks,
  Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do through Api only ?  because we can also do this through a observes also. You can use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` observer .

I had set my comment in the custom session variable and than get that on order success and set comment with below code.

I have also done something like this in my recent magento2 project

```
        <?php
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());

 $getordercomment =  $session->getOrderComment(); 
            if($getordercomment!=''){
                $history = $objectmanagersession->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\History');
                $history->setComment($getordercomment);
                $history->setParentId($order->getData('entity_id'));
                $history->setIsVisibleOnFront(1);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(0);
                $history->setEntityName('order');
                $history->setStatus($order->getData('status'));
                $history->save();
                $session->setOrderComment(""); //  to empty last session message
            } 
?>
```

Comment: can you please give me idea about $objectmanagersession ? how can i get that ? it will be a great help if you can give this.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Basically I would like to have a dedicated API that set that comment and that comment should be translated in the relative order comment. I am designing a solution for this, and (hopefully! :) ) I will share my solution during the next days

Comment: ok great hope by seeing that it will more clear how we can done this more logically